# How do I edit the calling cell of a custom function with google apps script from within the custom function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

After searching through [various questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54414/in-google-script-get-the-spreadsheet-cell-calling-a-custom-function/54728#54728?newreg=ff25e795660647898b4ed36a017b6456) and the documentation I still cannot edit the calling cell of a custom function. According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactivecell):

> Returns the range of cells that is currently considered active. This
>   generally means the range that a user has selected in the active
>   sheet, but in a custom function it refers to the cell being actively
>   recalculated.

Although this description is for the getActiveRange() function one assumes the getActiveCell() functions in the same way.

I am trying to call a helper function from within my custom function which should return the 'active cell' which, to my knowledge, should be the calling cell of the custom function. Not working code:

```
// returns the current active (calling) cell for use within custom functions
function callingCell() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getActiveRange()
}

// change background colour of calling cell
function getInfoFromPublicApi(type) {
      ... // get prices using UrlFetchApp
      callingCell().setBackground('green')
      return averagePrice(prices, type)
}
```

I have also tried using the SpreadsheetApp from within the custom function directly, as well as using:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell()
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpeadsheet().getActiveRange()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go about it two ways. First, set calling cell as a variable. You cannot chain methods together like you're trying to do in the larger function. Or, you can drop the `callingCell()` function because the information is handled in the `event` object of `onEdit()`.

**Method 1**

```js
// returns the current active (calling) cell for use within custom functions
function callingCell() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getActiveRange();
}

// change background colour of calling cell
function getInfoFromPublicApi(type) {
  var active = callingCell();

  ... // get prices using UrlFetchApp
  active.setBackground('green')
  return averagePrice(prices, type)
}
```

**Method 2**

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  // Not sure what your `type` param is, so you'd need to test for that somehow.
  ... // get prices using UrlFetchApp
  e.getRange().setBackground('green');
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer! However method 1 did not solve my problem (tried saving the function in variable as you did and splitting up the chained function calls into 3 lines).

Comment: Method 2 is very undesirable in my situation since the functions called within the spreadsheet go through a series of computations -- basically hitting different stock exchanges which return differently formatted responses - and parsing all that information into a final function which returns the average. Doing it via onEdit would mean encapsulating all the program logic inside that function, when what I really want to do is change the colour of the cell after each individual API call!

Comment: In that case, @I'-'I is correct. Without the `onEdit` event, you cannot find the last edited cell with `SpreadsheetApp`. You can look at the Advanced Spreadsheet Service for more functionality.

Comment: Seems counter to what the docs specify, but that certainly seems the case @Brian. Will leave this Q open and update title to reflect needs more clearly